# Can get script compiled with CSharpScript (Roslyn)

Tags: roslyn, csharpscript

I'm trying to get a script compiled with Roslyn but whatever I do it keeps complaining about this, at this moment I tried almost everything and have no idea what to try next.

This is the error I get :

'(11,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name '' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

It is complaining that the namespace can't be found

I already added the references to the file and even added the assemblies to the InteractiveAssemblyLoader but still no luck.

```
        try
        {
#if (DEBUG)
            var metadataReferences = ApplicationSettings.Instance.GetValuesAsStringList("Script editor", "MetadataReferences_VOP");
#else
            var metadataReferences = ApplicationSettings.Instance.GetValuesAsStringList("Script editor", "MetadataReferences");
#endif

            var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default.WithEmitDebugInformation(true);
            scriptOptions.AddReferences(metadataReferences);

            using var assemblyLoader = new InteractiveAssemblyLoader();

            foreach(var reference in metadataReferences)
                assemblyLoader.RegisterDependency(Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(reference)));

            scriptRunner = CSharpScript
                .Create<string>(script, scriptOptions, typeof(MainGlobals), assemblyLoader)
                .ContinueWith("new NewEmail().Main(Email)")
                .CreateDelegate();

            exception = null;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exception = e;
            scriptRunner = null;
            return false;
        }
```

Is there somebody that has an idea about what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the AddReferences returns a new scriptOptions object that is the one with the added references :-)

So the solution was easy, just do this

scriptOptions = scriptOptions.AddReferences(metadataReferences);